# Views: how to remove ending zeros from decimal field

Tags: 7, views, entities

Suppose, we have a view with a decimal field:

[image]

It is output like this:

```
5 000.000
```

Is it possible to remove the ending zeros, so it looked like this:

```
5 000
```

But if there are meaningful values in the field, it should output all of them. For example:

```
5.100 -> 5.1
5.010 -> 5.01
5.001 -> 5.001
```

Comment: Look closer at your image..."The number of digits to the right of the decimal". Does that not have an option for 0?

Comment: @Clive But I want it to output all 3 digits, if there are meaningful values. So, it should output: 4.001. But if the value is 4.030 it should output: "4.03".

Comment: Ah, you didn't mention that in that question. In that case I don't think so, you'd probably need to write a custom field handler for that (unless you can find a module that provides one, but it's quite a niche requirement so you might not get lucky)

Comment: See https://www.drupal.org/node/636382 - similar issue, already with some code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I created a file /theme/bartik/templates/views-view-field--open-events--page--field-coefficient.tpl.php:

```
<?php
print (float) $row->_field_data['id']['entity']->field_coefficient[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
```

And it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a custom field formatter in a custom module. See drupal-root/modules/field/modules/number/number.module and copy the related stuff for 'number_decimal' and adapt it to "trim_decimal".

```
number_field_formatter_info()
number_field_formatter_settings_form()
number_field_formatter_settings_summary()
number_field_formatter_view()
```

In custom_module_field_formatter_view() define your formatter (here named: trim_decimal) like this:

```
...
case 'trim_decimal':
      foreach ($items as $delta => $item) {
        $output = number_format($item['value'], $settings['scale'], $settings['decimal_separator'], $settings['thousand_separator']);

        // If scale, we want to remove trailing 0 and the decimal separator,
        // if there are no digits after decimal separator.
        if ($settings['scale']) {
          $output = rtrim(rtrim($output, '0'), $settings['decimal_separator']);
        }

        if ($settings['prefix_suffix']) {
          $prefixes = isset($instance['settings']['prefix']) ? array_map('field_filter_xss', explode('|', $instance['settings']['prefix'])) : array('');
          $suffixes = isset($instance['settings']['suffix']) ? array_map('field_filter_xss', explode('|', $instance['settings']['suffix'])) : array('');
          $prefix = (count($prefixes) > 1) ? format_plural($item['value'], $prefixes[0], $prefixes[1]) : $prefixes[0];
          $suffix = (count($suffixes) > 1) ? format_plural($item['value'], $suffixes[0], $suffixes[1]) : $suffixes[0];
          $output = $prefix . $output . $suffix;
        }
        $element[$delta] = array('#markup' => $output);
      }
      break;
```